# Chances of 23 y/o getting approved for a £10k credit card to buy a car?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, car, purchase, application-process

So my old car has had its time and I'm looking to buy a 3-4 year old car for around £9-10k. I have personal savings exceeding this amount so buying in cash is an option, however I have recently learned about 'purchase credit cards' with 0% periods which are appealing for a few reasons:

- Provided I pay it within the 0% period (usually 18 months), it is free borrowing
- Allow me to make monthly payments without getting locked into the high interest rates and long terms of a PCP or HP
- Covered by section 75 in case there are any issues with the car
- Builds a good credit history

However, I am not sure of my eligibility due to my age (23) and income (£25k) and do not want to be laughed out of the bank by asking for such a high limit.

I have had a student credit card for the last few years as well as paying for various bills, so I have an Experian credit score of 999, as well as having the cash to hand and a proven track record of paying all bills in full either on time or early.

My question is, what is the likelihood that any bank would accept me for an account such as this? I have never actually applied for a credit card before so am not sure how limits and terms are gauged, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should consider whether a car dealership will accept payment by credit card before asking your bank. Unbeknownst to you, credit-card companies pay the merchant (car dealer) anywhere from 3% to 5% less than what you signed for, and so, if you whip out your credit card after signing a contract to buy a car for £10k, the dealership will either tear up the contract and show you the door, or insist on a new contract for x% more.

Comment: I have bought a few cars and they often allow a maximum of $2-3000 to be applied to a credit card.

Comment: @DilipSarwate No need for the dealer to act in such a harsh way. They also could ask for a diffrent payment method.

Comment: [This Autotrader article](https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-finance/guides/buying-a-car-using-a-credit-card) may be of interest.

Comment: You can apply online so you don't have to worry about getting laughed at.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It would be illegal for the dealer to ask for x% more. UK (and EU) consumer law bans surcharges for payment by card (but of course it doesn’t require anyone to accept credit cards). https://www.gov.uk/government/news/card-surcharge-ban-means-no-more-nasty-surprises-for-shoppers

Comment: James, since everyone is ignoring your question and giving "general car advice".  You probably (obviously) know this already, but don't forget, car *upkeep* is staggeringly expensive in the UK. (Indeed, that's thought to be one of the "freakonomics" reasons why, indeed, used cars are so incredibly cheap in the UK compared to anywhere else.)  Unless you truly need an amazing car for some reason, I would urge you to consider buying the cheapest one possible. Don't forget that **either a £500 car or a £10,000 car can equally, completely randomly, have a hugely expensive repair.**  Pure crap shoot

Comment: @DilipSarwate , your comment is somewhat odd, and I dunno why it got 11 votes!  (1) for example, a friend (US, not UK) recently bought a car, credit card, about $11,000 and it was a total non-issue, she just paid and nobody mentioned anything (2) many (not all) dealers (UK) normally accept c/c, even for large amounts, it's totally normal (3) not that it matters but the merch. fee is often less for large amounts / car dealers  (4)  nobody would "tear stuff up and show you the door". When you arrive you just say "oh I'll be paying by card is that fine?" it's totally unremarkable.

Comment: its inconceivable at a dealer you'd get to the point of "making a deal" without discussing in detail the payment approach to be used.

Answer (score 2):

These days there exist various credit card eligibility calculators which only conduct soft searches (ie they do NOT count as a credit application for credit file purposes). Try some of them and see if they give estimated credit limits (I'm not sure if they do or not).

Examples of such:

[MoneySavingExpert](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/eligibility/credit-cards/search/?goal=CC_PURCHASE)

[uSwitch](https://www.uswitch.com/credit-cards/eligibility-checker/?c=purchase)

[Compare the Market](https://credit-cards-eligibility.comparethemarket.com)

Comment: a great answer to the ACTUAL question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for auto loans instead of credit card based purchase. Auto loans are pretty straight forward approach. The reasons to go for auto loans are:

- Auto loans generally have lower interest rates compared to credit cards
- How much are you sure that you will pay off the loan within 18 months ? If you are not able to do so, might get into bigger debt problem.
- What is the guarantee that the credit card does not change the 0% interest ?
- When you go for bigger credit card debt, your credit score will get affected, as credit to debt ratio will increase.

Personally, I prefer debit card over credit card. I would suggest you to save money and then buy car. If you very much need the car, go for auto loans.

**Update**
I missed to note that you have got cash already. As you are already having cash, why are you complicating the things by going for credit card. Have enough emergency fund and pay as much as cash as possible and go for remaining portion as auto loan. Or if you could wait, save some more money and pay the car fully using cash.

Comment: He says that he’s got the money right now. He’s just looking for an interest-free loan for 18 months.

Comment: @MikeScott, thanks for updating me. I missed to note that point.

Comment: @MikeScott, Updated my answer.

Comment: "Auto loans generally have lower interest rates compared to credit cards" .... ?? the whole point of the quetsion is the OP is considering one of the promotional ZERO % card deals.

Comment: @Fattie, I am considering the case, where in case the credit card is not paid on time. There is a probability and in that case, credit card debt can quickly get very high due to high interest rate

Comment: a good point, @VenkataramanR